# Delphi 'uses' clauses containing resource datatypes, like 'RT_RCDATA'

Tags: delphi, types, resources

What Delphi `uses` clauses are needed to access resource datatypes, like `RT_RCDATA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your needs.

- For VCL apps, you'd use `Windows` or `Winapi.Windows` if you are using namespace prefixes.
- For FMX cross-platform apps you'd use `System.Types`.

Answer (score 2):

`RT_RCDATA` and other `RT_...` values are defined in the `Windows` unit.

Comment: @JosephPoirier: Yes, but it seems like the rest of them only reside in `Windows`.

Comment: Found it in System.Types, but all the other ones are in Windows unit as you defined... using Delphi XE5 thx.

Comment: I created a startup folder in my project and just added all my resource files... testing the access now